# Multiple AND operators in CASE function in QGIS field calculator not returning results

Tags: qgis

I am trying to evaluate three attribute fields and return a different value. When I try this expression I get no return.

```
CASE
WHEN (Att_A =1) AND (Att_B = 2) AND (Att_C = 3) THEN 40
END
```

When I try it with 2 I get a return.

```
CASE
WHEN (Att_B = 2) AND (Att_C = 3) THEN 40
END
```

Can you not evaluate three items in a case statement in QGIS or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: And you definitely have data that satisfies the criteria (Att_A =1) AND (Att_B = 2) AND (Att_C = 3) ?  Try this:  `CASE
WHEN (Att_A =1) AND (Att_B = 2) AND (Att_C = 3) THEN 40
ELSE 999 END`  Do you get a result now?

Comment: Yes there are definitely rows that satisfy those criteria. I think there may be something wrong with my table or QGIS installation because after you implied that it should be possible I tried a simple Att_A =1 Then 40 and it only did some of them. So I tried it on a different table on another computer and the CASE with 2 ANDs worked fine. The field is an integer field that was calculated from other fields. Could it be corrupted some how?

Comment: Its does sound odd.  You should be able to combine 3 or more ANDs.  Sounds like you're on the right track with your troubleshooting, hope you get to the bottom of it.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Even though it is an integer field type and the values are shown as integers if in the field calculator I load the values from the field they show as decimals. I think this is because I created them by division they still contain the decimals. If I do "to_int" then the formula works. This seems like a bug.

Comment: Nice work. Thanks for the update, does seem like a bug.  You may have saved me from bumping up against this in the future.

Comment: As soon as I save the table as a geopackage the integer field takes over and trims the decimals but when it is a temporary table they are decimals. I was chaining a bunch of field creation algorithms together in the Graphical Modeler where they where staying as temporary tables. Thanks for your help.